# Detect if pressing a mouse button and which WinForm c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't want to click on a button or the form, I just want to know if user is pressing the left mouse button while the cursor is in the form.

I've tried this:

```
private void PlayForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.LButton)
    {
        ...
    }
 }
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried `PlayForm_Click()` but it works only when the click is on the 'canvas' if there's something else on top it won't work

Comment: `KeyDown` is not a mouse-related event. Maybe you want to use [`MouseDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: You'll have the same problem with MouseDown. Whichever control you have the mouse over will be the one that gets the mouse events. If that's a button, it'll get the mouse events. If there is no control, it'll be the form itself. You need to handle the event on the appropriate control.

Comment: @Sinatr no it acts the same way as  PlayForm_Click()

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820788/713847

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know if the left mouse button is down while executing some other code in the Form you can look at the static property `Control.MouseButtons`, which returns a value from the `MouseButtons` enumeration .E.g.:

```
if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the mouse enter/leave to set a boolean that the mouse cursor is over the form, then you could Use the Mouse.

```
...
        bool mouseOverMe;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mouseOverMe = false;
        }

        private void Window_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseOverMe = true;
        }

        private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseOverMe = false;
        }

        void doSomething()
        {
            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                if (mouseOverMe)
                    MessageBox.Show("Im a mouse down in the window");
        }
...
```

something sorta like this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, you want a handler for a click on whatever is in the form. I'd suggest you could iterate trough all the controls in the form on `Form_Load` event and just set a common handler for the `MouseClick` (or KeyPressed or whichever event you want according to your current need)  for all controls present in the `.Controls` collection in the moment the form is loaded and you should register the same handler for the form itself (a.k.a. `this.MouseClick`). This will be a bit of an overkill if you'd later want to register a MouseClick handler for a particular control, but you can always compare the `sender` object and get the data from there. Example code is not present for now, since I'm typing from my phone. Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the form doesn't get any messages when a message is sent directly to a child control.

One way around this is to register an application-wide message filter. Note that the following implementation is rather inefficient (and quite ugly), but it should show you the basic idea:

```
void Main()
{
  var form = new Form();
  form.Load += (s, _) => Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyFilter((Form)s));

  var pnl = new Panel();
  pnl.Controls.Add(new Button());
  form.Controls.Add(pnl);

  Application.Run(form);
}

public class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
{
  Form form;

  public MyFilter(Form form)
  {
    this.form = form;
    this.form.Disposed += (_, __) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
  }

  public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message msg)
  {
    const int WM_LMOUSEDOWN = 0x0201;

    if (msg.Msg == WM_LMOUSEDOWN && msg.HWnd != IntPtr.Zero 
        && Control.FromHandle(msg.HWnd).TopLevelControl == form)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```