# System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(): how do I check if it was raised by mouse or by code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Is there any way to detect if the `Resize` event was raised by dragging the `Form` interactively with the mouse cursor or by code changing control the Width/Height properties?

```
public class CustomControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
       // Am I dragging the window corner mouse cursor and left mouse button pressed
       // or somebody called Control.Width += 10 ?
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"Left mouse button pressed"* - should be [easy to check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820788/1997232).

Comment: We thought about this but it can be pressed for many other reasons...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [`Mouse.Captured`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.captured?view=netcore-3.1) property. If the control capturing the mouse is the form, chances are the user is resizing with the mouse.

You could get some false positives I guess but it should work reasonably well. That said, I am no expert in windows forms so there might be a cleaner way to figure out what triggered the resize event.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to detect if the Resize event is triggered by dragging

or code changing.

I write a code example and it can basically meet the requirement.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (t == true)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "This is rasied by by mouse";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "This is rasied by by code";
        }

    }
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            t = false;
            Control control = (Control)sender;

            // Ensure the Form remains square (Height = Width).
            if (control.Size.Height != control.Size.Width)
            {
                control.Size = new Size(control.Size.Width, control.Size.Width);
            }

        }
    }

    bool t = false;
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            t = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Besides, If you want to drag form, you need to click the form first.

Please look at the following result:

[image]